# Whether you need the word 'to' in the sentence - Which place do you want to go to?

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is correct and why?

1. Which do you want to go to?
2. Which do you want to go?

I am a native English speaker and was asked this by a Japanese person. I think number 2 is not correct but I don't know the reason why, or if in fact I am actually right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You're right, (2) is incorrect, and the reason is that the rule of *Wh*-Question Formation starts from a statement

> *You want to go to **which**.*

then Subject-Verb Inversion and Do-Support puts the *do* before *you* and *which* before *do*, leaving *to* at the end.

> *Which do you want to go to?*

Without the *to* at the end, however, the question would have to come from an ungrammatical sentence, since *go* does not take a direct object. The *to* is necessary as a direction for *go*.

> (Parenthetically, thank you for mentioning that you're a native speaker. We get a lot of questions where it's not clear, and it makes a difference.)